# Pass Value onclick on a div angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a div with click function. I want to pass a value to a material Dialog on click. I know how to do with ngModal on input. I don't know how to do this. Any ideas? Thanks.
HTML:

```
<div class="opportunitiesTiles" (click)="openDialog('Designer')">
```

Here is my Typescript:

```
export class OpportunitiesComponent implements OnInit {name: any;
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

 ngOnInit() {}

 openDialog(value): void {

const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PopupDialog, {
});
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log("The dialog was closed");
});}}
```

This is my modal:

```
@Component({
selector: "popup-dialog",
templateUrl: "./popupDialog.component.html"
})
export class PopupDialog {
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PopupDialog>) {}

 onNoClick(): void {
this.dialogRef.close();
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `openDialog` function and pass the value in `data`:

```
openDialog(value): void {
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PopupDialog, {
      data: { x: value },

    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(_result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
}
```

Now in your PopupDialog component, you can inject `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` in constructor to access the passed value like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: "popup-dialog",
    templateUrl: "./popupDialog.component.html"
})
export class PopupDialog {
  x: any;

  constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PopupDialog>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) {
    // here the received value is being assigned to class variable `x`
    this.x = data.x;
  }

    onNoClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}
```

For more options & detailed doc: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-

Comment: Awesome. That Worked. Thank you.